# Hibernate batch processing does not working even though already set the batch_size

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, hikaricp

I want to process bulk data around 1 million data using batch processing. 
Below is my config

```
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://68.183.186.212:5432/seribu_trx_db?reWriteBatchedInserts=true
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 2
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: id.usermanagement.user.dialect.CustomPostgreSqlDialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 20000
        generate_statistics: true
        order_inserts: true
```

service code:

```
List<TUserInfo> listUserInfo = this.getListUserInfo();
userRepository.saveAll(listUserInfo);
```

log:

```
Hibernate: insert into t_user_info (created_by, created_date, gender , id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into t_user_info (created_by, created_date, gender , id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into t_user_info (created_by, created_date, gender , id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into t_user_info (created_by, created_date, gender , id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into t_user_info (created_by, created_date, gender , id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_user_info")
public class TUserInfo implements Persistable<UUID> {
 @Id
 @Column
 private UUID id;
 @Column
 private String gender;
 @Column
 private String created_by;
 @Column
 private String created_date;

    @Override
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

but on the printed log, it seems like the process is not even batch process.
Anyone can help me? or any other approach about how to process bulk data?

Comment: please share your TUserInfo entity. How do you generate id ?

Comment: @MartinČuka just added.

Comment: Thos are the SQL queries that are added to the batch. And the batch is executed (i.e. sent to the database) once it has received 20000 queries. Everything is normal.

Comment: @JBNizet but I thought when use batch process, the log should be printed like this: 2018-06-16 00:23:14.698  INFO 9128 --- [           main] jdbc.sqlonly                             : batching 5 statements: 1: insert into application$model (name, id) values ('model0', '<byte[]>') 
2: insert into application$model (name, id) values ('model1', '<byte[]>') 3: insert into application$model 
(name, id) values ('model2', '<byte[]>') 4: insert into application$model (name, id) values 
('model3', '<byte[]>') 5: insert into application$model (name, id) values ('model4', '<byte. isnt it?

Comment: And I thought I would be rich enough to stop working at 30... But I'm 44, and I still need to work :-)